# Can I add other Custom Taxonomy to my syntax (functions.php)

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am using this syntax to remove excerpts on Custom Taxonomy archive listings and it works great:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length','remove_excerpt', 1000 );
function remove_excerpt( $length ) 
{
    if ( is_tax('country') ) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return $length;
}
```

However, I also have two other Custom Taxomoies....

Is this correct to add the other two like this?

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length','remove_excerpt', 1000 );
function remove_excerpt( $length ) 
{
    if ( is_tax('country') ) {
        return 0;
    } 
    elseif ( is_tax('us_state') ) {
        return 0;
    } 
    elseif ( is_tax('cities') ) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return $length;
}
```

I want the same result for all three...

Just want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

Thanks

Comment: * I tested it and it works fine. I just want to be sure and learn. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can also pass an array to `is_tax`:

```
if(is_tax(array('country', 'us_state', 'cities')) {
   return 0;
}
```

Give that a try, but otherwise what you have is fine.

Comment: Thanks. Would your solution save a tiny amount of time to execute? Just curious...

Comment: Possibly, but we would be talking fractions of a second. It just makes the code a little neater more than anything - especially if you had 5 or 10 taxonomies to check.